# Фильтрация по полю типа JSON с Postgres и SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

У меня есть таблица `test_table` вида:

```
 Column     |          Type          |
------------+------------------------+
 id         | integer                |
 attributes | json                   |
```

Содержание:

```
 id |    attributes
----+----------------------------
  1 | {"a": 1, "b": ["b1","b2"]}
  2 | {"a": 2, "b": ["b3"]}
  3 | {"a": 3}
```

И мне нужно отфильтровать данные по содержимому атрибута "b" поля `attributes`.
Я нашёл как это сделать с помощью SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM test_table
WHERE attributes ->> 'b' SIMILAR TO '%(b1|b3)%';
-- или
SELECT * FROM test_table 
WHERE attributes -> 'b' ?| array['b1', 'b3'];
```

Или используя сырой запрос в SQLAlchemy

```
stmt = select(test_table).where(text("attributes ->> 'LNAM_REFS' SIMILAR TO '%(b1|b3)%'"))
```

Возвращаемый результат:

```
 id |    attributes
----+----------------------------
  1 | {"a": 1, "b": ["b1","b2"]}
  2 | {"a": 2, "b": ["b3"]}
```

Но не могу понять как это сделать с помощью SQLAlchemy, но использования сырого запроса.
Postgres 9.6
SQLAlchemy 1.4

PS: Нашёл вариант, как сделать с помощью `like any`, но выглядит криво:

```
arr = ["b1", "b3"]
arr = [f"%{i}%" for i in arr]
stmt = select(test_table).where(cast(t.c.attributes["b"], String).like(any_(arr)))
```

Answer (score 0):

В английской версии подсказали [пару ответов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77626451/filtering-by-json-type-field-with-postgres-and-sqlalchemy).

```
arr = ["b1", "b3"]
stmt = select(test_table).where(func.jsonb_exists_any(cast(t.c.attributes["b"], JSONB), arr))
```

или

```
arr = ["b1", "b3"]
stmt = select(test_table).where(cast(t.c.attributes["b"],JSONB).has_any(array(tuple(arr))))
```

Оба варианта работают в Postgres 9.6.
Второй вариант начиная с 12 (вроде) версии можно упростить.

```
arr = ["b1", "b3"]
stmt = select(test_table).where(cast(t.c.attributes["b"],JSONB).has_any(arr))
```